# Spring: Required request body is missing. Can't Pass JSON to RestController

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm have issues with passing JSON to RestController. It doesn't seem to consume it.

**Controller:**

```
@PostMapping(path = "Users/{UserId}/Transactions",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<?>> startGameRound(@RequestBody TransactionRequest request,
                                                                            @RequestParam("PartnerUserSessionKey") String sessionId,
                                                                            @PathVariable("UserId") String playerUUID) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException { // Logic }
```

**`TransactionRequest`** Object Model:

```
public class TransactionRequest {
@JsonProperty("TransactionType")
private TransactionType transactionType;

@JsonProperty("TransactionId")
private String transactionId;

@JsonProperty("TransactionCreationDate")
private LocalDateTime transactionCreationDate;

@JsonProperty("Amount")
private Long amount;

@JsonProperty("Rake")
private BigDecimal rake;

@JsonProperty("CurrencyCode")
private String currencyCode;

@JsonProperty("EntityReferences")
private List<EntityReference> entityReferences;

@JsonProperty("Game")
private Game game;

public TransactionRequest() {
}
//getters & setters & hashEquals & toString 
}
```

And here is the **Test Method** that's trying to Post to the Controller:

```
def createTransactionRequest(Integer roundNum, String transType, BigDecimal transactionAmount) {

    def transactionRequest = builder{
        'TransactionType' transType
        'TransactionId' "${new Random().nextInt(50)}"
        'TransactionCreationDate' LocalDateTime.now().toString()
        'Amount' transactionAmount.longValue()
        'Rake' 0.0
        'CurrencyCode' userCurrencyCode
        'EntityReferences' builder.call([
                { 'EntityType' "CasinoRound"; 'EntityId' roundNum },
                { 'EntityType' "CasinoSession"; 'EntityId' gameSessionId }
        ])
        'Game' (GameId: "111", GameName: "Some Game")
    }

    String currentDate = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")).format(DATE_FORMATTER)
    def authorizationHeader = buildAuthHeader("POST",
            "Users/${player.uuid}/Transactions?PartnerUserSessionKey=$gameSessionId",
            JsonOutput.toJson(transactionRequest), currentDate)

    return client.post(path: "Users/${player.uuid}/Transactions", query: ["PartnerUserSessionKey": gameSessionId],
            headers: ['Authorization' : authorizationHeader, DateUtc : currentDate]) {
        type "application/json"
        json transactionRequest
    }

}
```

Test method is written in Groovy. And Builder as in `groovy.json.JsonBuilder`. (Ignore `authorizationHeader` method it's just for generating Signature for Authorization, it works) I've tried just Sending several parameters only but it would give me same Error every time. Here is the Error:

```
2017-09-05 12:38:26,005 WARN  c.n.c.e.CommonExceptionHandler - Required request body is missing: public java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture<org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?>> com.project.TransactionEndpoint.startGameRound(com.project.api.TransactionRequest,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException,java.lang.InterruptedException
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture<org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?>> com.project.endpoint.TransactionEndpoint.startGameRound(com.project.api.TransactionRequest,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException,java.lang.InterruptedException
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:127)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
```

I believe it has something to do Object Model but not sure what. I've tried passing different combinations but no luck. It would just give me `Required request body is missing`.

Here is the resulting JSON:

```
{"TransactionType":"CasinoRound_Stake","TransactionId":"31","TransactionCreationDate":"2017-09-05T15:38:08.610","Amount":400,"Rake":0.0,"CurrencyCode":"EUR","EntityReferences":[{"EntityType":"CasinoRound","EntityId":1},{"EntityType":"CasinoSession","EntityId":"9f31d8b9-28f7-4931-bb9d-73f90c2b2de7"}],"Game":{"GameId":"111","GameName":"Some Game"}}
```

Comment: I'm curious what the line type "application/json" is in there with the body. Shouldn't it be with the headers? Did this exact post setup worked in the past?

Comment: @Assafs Yea, it worked before in some cases. Even if I input type into the Headers, it would give me same Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a filter in which you have already read the body.